# 2 vBulletin forums sharing same user database?

Tags: database, share, vbulletin, forums

How would I fix so that 2 vBulletin forums share the same database?

And do not tell me it is not possible, cause it is.

http://MMOwned.com
http://FPSOwned.com

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a predefined set of tables that you want to share you may be able to use the [`FEDERATED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html) storage engine to "share" a table across two separate databases or perhaps the `MERGE` storage engine to effectively share a `MyISAM` table across two databases.

I'm not sure what fun and games you might run into with counters, etc inside vBulletin.

Have you had a good look on the vBulletin.org forums or asked the owner of mmowned.com how they did it?